# Grafana dashboard search from URL

Tags: grafana

I would like to generate Grafana URLs with a predefined search of a dashboard name.

Something like https://play.grafana.org/search=open&query=myDashboard leading to the search result page with all dashboard containing this name.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different Grafana approach, e.g:

```
https://play.grafana.org/dashboards?query=myDashboard&search=open
```

Comment: Thanks, very simple, it's exactly what I wanted